# Retrieve Values as Formulas in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

First time asking on here:

I have two workbooks in Excel.  One is linked to an external data source so it updates (called First).  The other is derived from the first (called Second).  Now, I'm trying for two things:

1. That Second works down the name column, reads in that name, then goes to First, works down its name column until it finds a match
   THEN
2. Three cells of data in the row with named item are copied and inserted to the corresponding cells in Second BUT they are formulas so that when First updates, Second will update with the new numbers.

I've been able to get it to run (at least with the first row of cells) but the line:
    `ActiveCell.Formula = "='ID.Range("L" & C)'"` tells me its expecting an end statement.

This is the summation of what I want: "'If B2 = B2 Then Copy L2: M2, Insert into D3:F3" if not, continue until B2=B2 then Copy and =Insert

```
Sub QTY_Fill_2()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim C As Integer
Dim X As String
Dim Y As String
Dim D As Integer
Static DD_Name As String
Static Name As String
Dim ID_Name As Variant
Dim ID As Worksheet
Dim DD As Worksheet
Dim ID_Item_No As String
Dim DD_Item_No As String

Set ID = Workbooks("First").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set DD = Workbooks("Second").Sheets("Inventory")

For j = 2 To 2
G = j
DD_Name = DD.Range("B" & G).Value
MsgBox ("DD_Name =" & DD_Name)

    For i = 2 To 2
    C = i
Workbooks("First").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ID_Name = ID.Range("B" & C).Value
MsgBox ("ID_Name =" & ID_Name)
If DD_Name = ID_Name Then MsgBox ("Names Match")
If DD_Name <> ID_Name Then MsgBox ("No match")
If DD_Name = ID_Name Then ID.Range("L" & C).Copy

DD.Activate
Range("D" & C).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "='ID.Range("L" & C)'"

Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & ID.Range("L" & C).Address(1,1,xlA1,1)`

Comment: Great! That worked. Now, the harder part.  How do I go about having the names compare then having the corresponding row number used? I.e. Data from the 10th row of the First document is being copied into the 10th row of the Second document but the Items are not matching so incorrect data is being pasted.  So while it is checking for matching names, it isn't linking the row number of the match and inserting the corresponding data.

Comment: I think I got it, I want to use G for the Second sheet and J for the First in the cell coordinates.